# If did not receive a solution after setting bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties

What should I do whenever I do not receive a correct solution for my question even set a bounty?

Comment: Set another bounty?

Comment: What question are we talking about here, anyway? I don't see that you've ever offered a bounty.

Answer (score 4):

One of the probable reason your post not getting the answer is **content** of your post, make it more detailed and understandable. Put your code, if possible demo like jsFiddle or others should be created and use an example in your post, tag with correct tagged.

If still not getting answer, your problem might be a bit complicated and consider no one knows it and try to solve it yourself and don't forget to reply on your own post so others can get the advantage.